# How to select one record per user?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, users and hra. A user can only have one record in users table, but he can have multiple hras. What I want to do is only retrieve one hra per user. I have the query below. Anyone can help to do that?

```
$query = "SELECT u.id AS user_id, h.id AS hra_id FROM users u
          INNER JOIN hra h ON u.id = h.user_id
          WHERE h.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
          AND h.done = 1
```

Comment: Which HRA do you want? Why do you only want one?

Comment: Is there a specific `hra` that you want to retrieve, or are you happy with any `hra` that satisfies your `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the MAX(h.id), this should work:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, MAX(h.id) AS hra_id FROM users u
      INNER JOIN hra h ON u.id = h.user_id
      WHERE h.date BETWEEN ? AND ?
      AND h.done = 1
 GROUP BY u.id
```